# agGrid setting custom height for rows in infinite mode makes the entire app laggy

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to set custom row height on infinite mode with `agGrid` and it resulted in the entire app getting laggy. the scroll on the columns (the horizontal scroll) is so laggy too.

here is my code for setting the rowHeight, it sets it based on individual rows and is called later in the getRows method after calling `successCallback` method.

```
let gridHeight = 0;

            self.gridOption.api.forEachNode(node => {
              let rowHeight = 80;
              node.setRowHeight(rowHeight);
              node.setRowTop(gridHeight);

              gridHeight += rowHeight;
            });

            let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-center-cols-clipper');
            if (elements) {
              elements[0].style.height = `${gridHeight}px`;
            }
```

i don't know why is this a thing really, but I also set the rowBuffer value to avoid flickering in the rows when applying the code above, it set it to 9999 which is a large number but not supposed to make it this laggy.
I am having it with agGrid really, is there any way of fixing this or maybe another way of setting the row height ?

Comment: Have you tried `gridOptions.rowHeight = 80;`, as documented [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/)?

Comment: that doesn't work in infinite mode, aggrid completely ignores that. look for it you'll find it that way.